# Using Ajax search functionality is not working, Not displaying any data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have implemented search functionality option in my web page.But the problem is unable to get the data displaying  blank page.I have checked in console there was no errors.Checked in console as their was no errors.

Here is the code for that

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
   <div class="container">
   <br/>
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
             <span class="input-group-addon">Search</span>
          <input type="text" name="search_text"  id="search_text" class="form_control"/>
          </div>
          </div>
          <br/>
          <div id="result"></div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
     <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){  
     $('#search_text').keyup(function(){
    var txt=$(this).val();
    if(txt!='')
    {

    }
    else
    {
        $('#result').html('');
        $.ajax({                
        url:"searchpatient.php",
        method:"post",
        data:{search:txt},  
        dataType:"text",
        success:function(data)
        {   
            $('#result').html(data);
        }               
        });     
        }
     });
     });
     </script>
```

Searchpatient.php

```
<?php 
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","learn");
$output =  '';
    $sql="SELECT * FROM appointment WHERE status='1' AND first_name LIKE '%".$_POST["search"]."%'";     
    $result=mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
    {           
        $output .='<h2>Patient Record</h2>';
        $output .='<div class="table-responsive">
                      <table class="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>                               
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Gender</th>
                            <th>Department</th>
                            <th>Phonenumber</th>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>Address</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>';
                        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))                                
                        $output .='<tr>
                                        <td>' . $row['first_name'].' </td>
                                        <td>' . $row['gender'].'</td>
                                        <td>' . $row['department'].'</td>
                                        <td>' . echo $row['phone_no'].'</td>                                            
                                        <td>' . echo $row['date'].'</td>                                            
                                        <td>' . echo $row['address'].'</td>                                           
                                    </tr>';                         
    }
    echo $output;
else{
    echo 'Data Not Found';
    }
  ?>
```

I have gone one of the tutorial from youtube and followed this one but their code has worked fine but for me its getting issues.Hope anyone get solution for this.Thank you in advance

Comment: Does it even reach searchpatient.php? Try an echo in your PHP script?

Comment: @Erdss4 unable to get you

Comment: Do you even know if your ajax call gets to searchpatient.php at all? Use an echo in PHP to test if it you reach it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<br/>
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
             <span class="input-group-addon">Search</span>
          <input type="text" name="search_text"  id="search_text" class="form_control"/>
          </div>
          </div>
          <br/>
          <div id="result"></div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#search_text').keyup(function(){
 var txt=$(this).val();
 if(txt!='')
 {
$('#result').html('');
$.ajax({
url:"searchpatient.php",
       method:"post",
       data:{search:txt},
dataType:"text",
success:function(data)
{
$('#result').html(data);
}
});
}
});
});
</script>
```

searchpatient.php

```
<?php 
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","learn");
$output =  '';
    $sql="SELECT * FROM appointment WHERE status='1' AND first_name LIKE '%".$_POST["search"]."%'";     
    $result=mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
    {           
        $output .='<h2>Patient Record</h2>';
        $output .='<div class="table-responsive">
                      <table class="table table-striped">
                        <thead>
                          <tr>                               
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Gender</th>
                            <th>Department</th>
                            <th>Phonenumber</th>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>Address</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>';

                        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))                                
                        $output .='<tr>
                                        <td>' . $row['first_name'].' </td>
                                        <td>' . $row['gender'].'</td>
                                        <td>' . $row['department'].'</td>
                                        <td>' . $row['phone_no'].'</td>                                         
                                        <td>' . $row['date'].'</td>                                         
                                        <td>' . $row['address'].'</td>                                           
                                    </tr>';     
        echo $output;
    }       
else{
    echo 'Data Not Found';
    }
    ?>
```